# Already installed libraries missing after running the code

Tags: python, cluster-computing

I am trying to run a code in a virtual python environment on a cluster. Here, I installed all the relevant libraries such as h5py, plotly, tqdm, mpi4py and vtk using pip install ____ command and all of these libraries installed just fine. But when I run my code, the system start asking for these libraries again. At this point, if I try to reinstall these libraries I get prompts like:

> WARNING: The directory '/gpfs/fs1/home//a5saieed/.cache/pip' or its
> parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user.
> The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that
> directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
> Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not
> writeable

sudo command doesn't work since it's a cluster on which I do not have the right to use it.

What might be causing this problem and what could be it's possible solution?

.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[you should not use sudo with pip](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802544/is-sudo-pip-install-still-a-broken-practice#:%7E:text=Both%20sudo%20pip%20install%20and,PyPI%20(Python%20Package%20Index).) while having virtualenv activated.
Try install the libraries in this way:

```
# installs on virtualenv's python:
$ .env/bin/python -m pip install yourlibrary
```

Comment: I tried it, but its still stuck. Now it is not asking for the libraries but it is giving the following error:
srun: error: PMK_KVS_Barrier duplicate request from task 0

Weird part is this code was working just two days ago, on the same environment. All I did differently was, I tested it on a single node and then I submitted the job on slurm for mpirun. After this things aren't working anymore. Even the same approach.

Comment: Thats another diferent question. Can you publish it independently?

Comment: And mark my answer as solution for the original question?

Comment: Is `~/.env` or `./.env` a particular virtual environment installed explicitly in that location?  If the latter, what is that directory relative to?  I looked in the venv dirs themselves and don't see it there.  I've never been aware of a pseudo-location for a virtual env being `~/.env` or `./.env`.  I just looked on a number of Linux servers, as well as my Mac, for that directory, and I can't find it even though we use virtual environments on all of our servers.  Some were CentOS and some were Ubuntu.  Some explanation of what's up with that would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Steve, hope this solve your doubts: https://advanced-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup/virtualenv.html#location-of-virtualenvs

Comment: I don't see how that link solves anything.  You refer to the directory `.env`, but you give no description of what that directory is.  The docs you reference do not mention the name `.env` anywhere, so it doesn't help explain what that directory is.  I recommend that you explain in your answer what and where the `.env` directory is, and how it came to be.  I assume it's just the root dir of an arbitrary virtual environment, but if that's the case, `.env` is a strange thing to name one arbitrary virtual environment, especially since it' a directory that will be hidden.  Seems confusing.

Comment: @Steve the 'env' directory name is a convention. In the documentation they named the virtualenv directory as "class"(where "class" will be the folder where all your dependencies will be stored and isolatred from your system to prevent breaking any system-wide packages). You can create a virtualenv whith the name of your choice. You are free to Read the docs improve my answer with a edit or downvote as your choice. I think the answer it's pretty concise.